# Peetre's Inequality - not strict?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

> (Peetre's inequality)
>       Let $x,y \in \Bbb R^n$ and $s \in \Bbb R$. Then 
>       $$ \frac{(1+|x|^2)^s}{(1+|y|^2)^s} \le 2^{|s|} (1+|x-y|^2)^{|s|}.$$

Proof: By switching roles of $x,y$ we may suppose $s \ge 0$, and taking $s$th root may assume $s=1$. Then the *argument i found online:*

\begin{align*}
(1+|x|^2) &=  1 + |x-y|^2 + |y|^2 +2(x-y)y  \\ 
 & \le 1 + |x-y|^2 + |y|^2 + (|x-y|^2+|y|^2) \\ 
& \le 2(1+|y|^2 + |x-y|^2 +|y|^2|x-y|^2 ) \\ 
& = 2(1+|y|^2)(1+|x-y|^2).
\end{align*}

---

What I don't understand is that on the third inequality, isn't this clearly a **strict inequality when $s\not= 0$? (at least by 1)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. We have that for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$,
\begin{align*}
(1+|x|^2) &=1+|(x-y)+y|^2\\
&=  1 + |x-y|^2 + |y|^2 +2\langle (x-y), y \rangle \\ 
&\leq  1 + |x-y|^2 + |y|^2 +2|x-y| |y| \\ 
 & \le 1 + |x-y|^2 + |y|^2 + (|x-y|^2+|y|^2) \\ 
 & = 1+ 2|y|^2 + 2|x-y|^2  \\ 
 & < 2+ 2|y|^2 +2|x-y|^2 +2|y|^2|x-y|^2 \\ 
& = 2(1+|y|^2)(1+|x-y|^2).
\end{align*}

Comment: if you have time I hope you don't mind giving me some comments on my recent question on elliptic operator.

Comment: I read the other question but I don't know much about  elliptic operators. I did not know  even  Peetre's Inequality, but as far as I understand, in its applications in PDE, a "strict" inequality is not so important. Am I wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately I am new to this, so I do not know ...

Comment: I have simplified the problem   now - does this seem easier?